# Have a weird question when using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I tried to run **nginx** like following:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
   web:
     image: nginx
     ports:
       - "3011:80"
```

After I run **docker-compose up**, I found that nginx working success at 127.0.0.1:3011

But if I copy the [nginx's dockerfile](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/3b108b59619655e3bd4597a059f544afa374b7fb/mainline/stretch/Dockerfile) at dockerHub:

And change the **docker-compose.yml** like following:

```
version: '3'

services:
   web:
     build: 
       context: .
       dockerfile: Dockerfile
     ports:
       - "3011:80"
```

Then nginx won't working at 127.0.0.1:3011.

Why is that?

Comment: tested this using the dockerfile linked above and the compose for it, this worked perfectly fine on my side. 

Perhaps you need to run `docker-compose build` and then `docker-compose up --force-recreate` it may be that you are using a stale container that may be broken.

Comment: Wow, thanks man! It works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great! Moving this to the answer section ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tested this using the dockerfile linked above and the compose for it, this worked perfectly fine on my side. Perhaps you need to run docker-compose build and then docker-compose up --force-recreate it may be that you are using a stale container that may be broken.

Comment: Thanks man, can you edit your answer? So that someone in future might knowing more clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you changed you Dockerfile, you should run

```
docker-compose up --build -d
```

to build your docker image before docker-compose runs it up.